# Program not returning

Tags: java, recursion, divide-and-conquer

i want to find a "peak value" in an array (a value where a1 ai+1>...>an, ai being the peak value here). I am using divide and conquer for a more optimum solution here. For" 6 1 3 50 70 100 48", it will print "70 100 48 4" which is good ( 70 < 100 and 100 > 48) but it does not return Integer.toString(a[m]), it returns "Array has no peak". I tried removing string and working with int but i get the exact same issue.

```
public class Main {

    public int n, a[];

    void read() {
        File file = new File("src/com/fmi/Vector.txt");
        Scanner sc;

        try {
            sc = new Scanner(file);
            int i = 0;
            if (sc.hasNextInt()) {
                n = sc.nextInt();
            }
            a = new int[n];
            while (sc.hasNextInt()) {
                int aux = sc.nextInt();
                a[i] = aux;
                i++;
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File not found!");
        }
    }

    String search(int p, int u) {
        int m;
        System.out.println(p + " " + u);
        if (p == u) {
            return "0";
        } else {
            m = (p + u) / 2;
            System.out.println(a[m - 1] + " " + a[m] + " " + a[m + 1] + " " + m);
            if (a[m - 1] < a[m] && a[m] > a[m + 1]) {
                return Integer.toString(a[m]);
            } else if (a[m - 1] < a[m] && a[m] < a[m + 1]) {
                search(m, u);
            } else if (a[m - 1] > a[m] && a[m] > a[m + 1]) {
                search(p, m);
            }
        }
        return "Array has no peak!";
    }

    void display() {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println(" ");
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.print(i + " ");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main obj = new Main();
        obj.read();
        System.out.println(obj.search(0, obj.n));
        obj.display();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format your code. Horrible to read.

Comment: Remove the file reading and add the values directly in the code. This both makes sure that the problem isn't with the file reading, and allows us to reproduce the error.

Comment: And try to simplify those conditions. have you debugged and checked the actual calls to search and the values your conditions test?

Comment: Do you mean `return search(m,u)` and `return search(p,m)` instead of `search(m,u)` and `search(p,m)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling search but you're not doing anything with the result.
You should do something like

```
return search(m,u);
```

Comment: oh, i missed that. Thanks!